# how to grep a value stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, aix

I am writing a bash script in which I am storing current date in a variable and then I am greping that variable. Issue is it's not working

```
currentdate= $(date +%b\ %d)
echo "$currentdate"
last |grep -E '$currentdate'>> /usr/IBM/HTTPServer7/logs/alert/users.txt
```

`users.txt` is showing empty. If I write manually the current date then it works.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Single quotes `'` vs. double quotes `"`. The former won't expand variables.

Comment: remove that space between = and $ in currentdate. and date syntax in last is like `DEC 1` . that date command returns `DEC 01`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the quotes, you also need to account for the date format used by the `last` command, which looks like the following:

```
Dec  3    # Note the padding to the left of '3'.
Nov 23
```

This requires a slightly different date command:

```
date "+%b %_d"
Dec  4
```

The underscore instructs `date` to pad the field with spaces. You can also use %e as an alternative.

Putting these together, you can modify your script as shown below:

```
currentdate=$(date "+%b %_d")
last | grep "$currentdate" >> /usr/IBM/HTTPServer7/logs/alert/users.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sparhawk is correct.

Double quotes cause the shell to expand variables.

```
$ VAR=blahblah
$ echo "$VAR"
blahblah
```

Single quotes cause the shell to use the text literally.

```
$ VAR=blahblah
$ echo '$VAR'
$VAR
```

You would use this if you wanted to prevent the shell from thinking a dollar sign plus some other text was a variable.

```
echo 'This script is terminating because you didn't set $IMPORTANT_VARIABLE'
```

Without single quotes the above message wouldn't output properly.

Comment: Issue is with this command
all though currentdate has correct value which is today Dec 04 but in users.txt the file is empty .  
last |grep -E '$currentdate'>> /usr/IBM/HTTPServer7/logs/alert/users.txt

if i use actual value Dec 04 in the above command the result is fine .